# How to plot the "trapping region" in Henon Map?

Tags: plotting, regions, nonlinear, difference-equations, recreational-mathematics

I am writing a paper that makes use of the Henon map. I have managed to plot the Henon map but now require plotting the "trapping region" shown in the image.

[image]

Do I require to plot it as a solid region or can use a dashed boundary? Also, I would want to label it as region 'R' inside, possibly shaded.

Comment: [What is a trapping region?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2319302/what-is-a-trapping-region). Wiki page on [Hénon map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A9non_map).

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code.

Comment: Do you just want to plot the quadrilateral given its vertices, or do you want to find it based on the Henon map?  If the latter, can you provide a reference to how that is done mathematically?

Comment: @ChrisK I was looking for the mathematical explanation, so I can try and code it up.

Comment: @Awnon:  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4063271/finding-a-trapping-region-for-the-h%c3%a9non-map and the cited Henon paper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Awnon:  Not sure if you're up on Mathematica syntax.  Here's some code that may help you:  One option to generate both the attractor, and its basin is to use `NestWhileList`:  Iterate the Henon map a set number of times and check if the absolute value exceeds a certain number.  In many attractors, that's 2.  If the iterated sequence does this before say 10 or so, then the orbit is likely not onto the attractor.  The points that do map to the attractor lie in its basin of attraction and is the region in light blue below.  So first generate the attractor and that trapping region with the data from the Henon reference I cited above:

```
alpha = 1.4;
beta = 0.3;
henon[alpha_, beta_][{x_, y_}] := {y + 1 - alpha x^2, beta x}
list = NestList[henon[1.4, 0.3], {0, 0}, 10000];
henonP = ListPlot[list, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}, PlotStyle -> Red];
trapG = Graphics@{FaceForm[LightRed], EdgeForm[Black], 
   Polygon[{{-1.33, 0.42}, {1.32, 
      0.133}, {1.245, -0.14}, {-1.06, -0.5}}]}
Show[{henonP, trapG}]
```

Next, create a matrix of points in the region $-2\leq x\leq 2$ and $-2\leq y\leq 2$ to be uses in an `ArrayPlot`.

```
xmin2 = -2.;
xmax2 = 2.;
ymin2 = -2.;
ymax2 = 2.;
jTerm = 2 xmax2;
iTerm = 2 ymax2;
totalPlotLength = 250;

plotRangeB = {{xmin2, xmax2}, {ymin2, ymax2}};
testTable = 
  Array[#1 &, {totalPlotLength, 
    totalPlotLength}, {{xmin2, xmax2}, {ymin2, ymax2}}];
```

Now iterate each point in `testTable` checking if abs value of x or y exceeds 2 and if a point maps to the attractor, set it's point in `testTable` to 1 otherwise 0:

```
For[j = 1, j <= totalPlotLength, j++,
  xVal = xmin2 + j jTerm/totalPlotLength;
  For[i = 1, i <= totalPlotLength, i++,
   yVal = ymax2 - i iTerm/totalPlotLength;
   val = NestWhileList[{#[[2]] + 1 - alpha #[[1]]^2, 
       beta #[[1]]} &, {xVal, 
      yVal}, (Abs[#[[2]] + 1 - alpha #[[1]]^2] < 2 || 
        Abs[beta #[[1]]] < 2) &, 1, 100];
   If[Length@val > 99,
    testTable[[i, j]] = 1;
    ,
    testTable[[i, j]] = 0;
    ];
   ];
  ];
```

Create a  color table to color the rules in `testTable`:  Blue for 1 and white for 0:

```
colorRules = {0 -> White, 1 -> LightBlue}
```

Draw the basin of attraction for the Henon attractor:

```
ap = ArrayPlot[testTable, ColorRules -> colorRules, 
  DataRange -> plotRangeB, Axes -> True, Ticks -> Automatic, 
  Frame -> False]
```

Put everything together:

```
Show[{ap, henonP, trapG}, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> True, 
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]